# Shell script execution is not working in remote server Ansible (previous tasks executed successfully)

Tags: shell, ansible

I am not able to execute shell script remotely in Ansible. However, there are previous tasks in the same role (filebeat) that are executed in remote server successfully. I am running the following in local server 172.28.28.6 server to install and run filebeat in remote server 172.28.28.81

**Playbook: install-filebeat.yml:**

```
 hosts: filebeat-servers
  remote_user: wwwadm
  sudo: yes
  roles:
  - { role: /vagrant/roles/filebeat}
```

**Role filebeat: main.yml:**

```
---
# tasks file for filebeat
- name: "Extract Filebeat"
  unarchive:
    src: "{{ tmp_artifact_cache }}/{{ filebeat_archive }}"
    remote_src: yes
    dest: "{{ filebeat_root_dir }}"
    extra_opts: ['--transform=s,/*[^/]*,{{ filebeat_ver }},i', '--show-stored-names']
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ filebeat_install_as }}"
  when: not ansible_check_mode 
  tags: [ 'filebeat' ]

- name: Configure Filebeat
  template: 
    src: "filebeat.yml.j2"
    dest: "{{ filebeat_install_dir }}/filebeat.yml"
    mode: 0775
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ filebeat_install_as }}"
  tags: [ 'filebeat' ]

- name: 'Filebeat startup script'
  template: 
    src: "startup.sh.j2" 
    dest: "{{ filebeat_install_dir }}/bin/startup.sh" 
    mode: 0755
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ filebeat_install_as }}"
  tags: [ 'filebeat', 'start' ]

#This one does not get executed at all:
- name: "Start Filebeat"
  # shell: "{{ filebeat_install_dir }}/bin/startup.sh"
  command: "sh {{ filebeat_install_dir }}/bin/startup.sh"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ filebeat_install_as }}"
```

**defaults:**

```
# defaults file for filebeat
filebeat_ver: "6.6.0"
filebeat_archive: "filebeat-{{ filebeat_ver }}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
filebeat_archive_checksum : "sha1:d38d8fea7e9915582720280eb0118b7d92569b23"
filebeat_url: "https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/{{ filebeat_archive }}"

filebeat_root_dir: "{{ apps_home }}/filebeat"
filebeat_data_dir: "{{ apps_data }}/filebeat"
filebeat_log_dir: "{{ apps_logs }}/filebeat"
filebeat_install_dir: "{{ filebeat_root_dir }}/{{ filebeat_ver }}"

filebeat_cert_dir: "/etc/pki/tls/certs"
filebeat_ssl_certificate_file: "logstash.crt"
filebeat_ssl_key_file: "logstash.key"

filebeat_install_as: "{{ install_user | default('wwwadm') }}"

filebeat_set_as_current: yes
filebeat_force_clean_install: no

filebeat_java_home: "{{ sw_home }}/jdk"
```

**inventory/local/hosts:**

```
localhost ansible_connection=local

[filebeat-servers]
172.28.28.81 ansible_user=vagrant ansible_connection=ssh
```

Filebeat is installed and changes are done in the remote server except the last step which is the execution of shell script

When running the playbook as follows:

```
ansible-playbook -i /vagrant/inventory/local install-filebeat.yml -vvv
```

Getting the following output related to the shell execution:

```
TASK [/vagrant/roles/filebeat : Start Filebeat] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /vagrant/roles/filebeat/tasks/main.yml:184
<172.28.28.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 172.28.28.81 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~vagrant && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.28.28.81> (0, '/home/vagrant\n', '')
<172.28.28.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 172.28.28.81 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.28.28.81> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606=/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<172.28.28.81> PUT /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-13658UX7cBC/tmpFzf2Ll TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/AnsiballZ_command.py
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 '[172.28.28.81]'
<172.28.28.81> (0, 'sftp> put /home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-13658UX7cBC/tmpFzf2Ll /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<172.28.28.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 172.28.28.81 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:wwwsvr:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.28.28.81> (0, '', '')
<172.28.28.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 -tt 172.28.28.81 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n -u wwwsvr /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ntzchfzqggiteuqwzpiurlloddbdhevp; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<172.28.28.81> (0, '\r\n{"changed": true, "end": "2019-02-14 13:09:44.800191", "stdout": "Starting Filebeat", "cmd": ["sh", "/apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/startup.sh"], "rc": 0, "start": "2019-02-14 13:09:43.792122", "stderr": "+ export JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk\\n+ JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk\\n+ echo \'Starting Filebeat\'\\n+ /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /apps_data/logs/filebeat", "delta": "0:00:01.008069", "invocation": {"module_args": {"warn": true, "executable": null, "_uses_shell": false, "_raw_params": "sh /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/startup.sh", "removes": null, "argv": null, "creates": null, "chdir": null, "stdin": null}}}\r\n', 'Shared connection to 172.28.28.81 closed.\r\n')
<172.28.28.81> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<172.28.28.81> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/vagrant/.ansible/cp/f66f05c055 172.28.28.81 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1550178583.24-35955954120606/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<172.28.28.81> (0, '', '')
changed: [172.28.28.81] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": [
        "sh",
        "/apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/startup.sh"
    ],
    "delta": "0:00:01.008069",
    "end": "2019-02-14 13:09:44.800191",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "sh /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/startup.sh",
            "_uses_shell": false,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2019-02-14 13:09:43.792122",
    "stderr": "+ export JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk\n+ JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk\n+ echo 'Starting Filebeat'\n+ /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /apps_data/logs/filebeat",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "+ export JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk",
        "+ JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk",
        "+ echo 'Starting Filebeat'",
        "+ /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /apps_data/logs/filebeat"
    ],
    "stdout": "Starting Filebeat",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Starting Filebeat"
    ]
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
172.28.28.81              : ok=18   changed=7    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

On remote server:

```
[6.6.0:vagrant]$ cd bin
[bin:vagrant]$ ls -ltr
total 36068
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 wwwadm wwwadm 36927014 Jan 24 02:30 filebeat
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 wwwadm wwwadm      478 Feb 14 12:54 startup.sh
[bin:vagrant]$ pwd
/apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin
[bin:vagrant]$ more startup.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x

export JAVA_HOME="/sw_ux/jdk"

#To save pid into a file is an open feature: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/3577. There is no -p flag for filebeat to save the pid and then kill it.
echo 'Starting Filebeat'
/apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /a
pps_data/logs/filebeat &
```

No process running found by executing ps command

```
[bin:vagrant]$ ps -fea | grep filebeat | grep -v grep
```

However, if I connect to the remote server, I am able to run filebeat by executing the script with the user wwwadm and filebeat starts successfully:

```
[bin:wwwadm]$ pwd
/apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin

[bin:wwwadm]$ id
uid=778(wwwadm) gid=778(wwwadm) groups=778(wwwadm) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

[bin:wwwadm]$ ./startup.sh
+ export JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk
+ JAVA_HOME=/sw_ux/jdk
+ echo 'Starting Filebeat'
Starting Filebeat
+ /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /apps_data/logs/filebeat

[bin:wwwadm]$ ps -fea | grep filebeat | grep -v grep
wwwadm   19160     1  0 15:12 pts/0    00:00:00 /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/bin/filebeat -c /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config/filebeat.yml -path.home /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0 -path.config /apps_ux/filebeat/6.6.0/config -path.data /apps_data/filebeat -path.logs /apps_data/logs/filebeat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [`disown`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#Job-Control-Builtins-1) built-in command to inform the shell that it should not kill background processes when you disconnect; you can also use [`nohup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/nohup.1.html) for that same effect

Having said that, you are **for sure** solving the wrong problem, because if^H^Hwhen filebeat falls over, there is nothing monitoring that service to keep it alive. You'll want to use systemd (or its equivalent on your system) to ensure that filebeat stays running, and by using the mechanism designed for that stuff, you side-step all the "disown or nohup" business that causes you to ask S.O. questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `nohup` to run it in background.

> because when ansible exits, all processes associated with the session
>   will be terminated. To avoid this you should use `nohup`.

Correct command is:

```
- name: "Start Filebeat"
  # shell: "{{ filebeat_install_dir }}/bin/startup.sh"
  command: "nohup sh {{ filebeat_install_dir }}/bin/startup.sh &>> startup.log &"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ filebeat_install_as }}"
```